# Creando rutas en IONIC: Multiples abstract

Tags: angularjs, ionic

hoy vengo con una nueva duda resulta que estoy en ionic y estoy creando las rutas. Entiendo que la clase **abstract** es un boleano que me permite heredar hijos, es decir parto con tab y los hijos serian su selección tab/home, tab/ajustes, etc...

```
.state('tab', {  
    url: '/tab',  
    abstract: true,  
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'  
   })  

  .state('tab.home', {  
    url: '/home',  
    views: {  
      'tab-home': {  
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',  
        controller: 'homeCtrl'  
    }  
  }  
  })
```

Ahora pregunto ¿Como hago para tener dos clases abtractas?

Pregunto porque en primera instancia, al abrir la app, aparece la vista  **inicio** y quiero que esta herede dos vistas más **inicio/login** e **inicio/registro**. y cuando complete el registro en mi app o inicie session, se abra la vista tab y se ejecute normalmente como se creo.

Saludos.

Comment: disculpa, no entiendo bien la parte ultimo, donde dices que cuando complete registro, explícame esa parte bien.

Comment: cuando yo me registre en la app, al aceptar que me lleve al menu principal (las tab's)

Comment: Bueno entiendo lo que quieres hacer, es que cuando ingrese el usuario, y el inicio de sesión es exitoso, pase a una interfaz donde tenga tab's, corrígeme si es así como quieres

Comment: sep ese es el objetivo.

Comment: Bueno yo hice algo asi, pero creo que no use mas de una vista abstracta, si es que lo use, no se si te servira